# MapR driver discontinued for Apache Drill? What now?

Tags: apache-drill, mapr

With the demise of MapR, we are left with no active Drill drivers for ODBC or JDBC.
Considering the last version of the driver was released over a year ago and for Drill 1.15, what are our options as the development of Drill slowly diverges from the last release of the driver by MapR?

Comment: Please ask this question on Drill user / dev mailing lists - https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/ (make sure you are subscribed to receive the answer).

Comment: Please also don't spread FUD about the supposed "demise of MapR". We are still around and are now part of HPE. In particular, the ODBC and JDBC drivers we provided are still available. Ping the mailing list.

Comment: Sorry for the hasty conclusion, but your Wikipedia page on MapR says it "was" a company, makes it seem like it is no longer around.

The last MapR Drill ODBC Driver was release for Drill 1.15 in Oct 2018, more than year ago, and is incompatible with the current Drill 1.17, just wondering if someone has an alternative...